# How to select parent element with a particular class in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have the following element structure.

```
<ul class="pagination floatRight margin-top-3x margin-right-2x search-pagination-cntr" id="logs_link_pager"><li class="hide disabled"><a href="/marketing/videoCall/history/businessID/f1f0e0d3-4e47-ba1a-1d57-5f9d009a41db"></a></li>
    <li class="previous disabled"><a href="/marketing/videoCall/history/businessID/f1f0e0d3-4e47-ba1a-1d57-5f9d009a41db"><span aria-hidden="true" class="p0">« Previous</span></a></li>
    <li class="active"><a href="/marketing/videoCall/history/businessID/f1f0e0d3-4e47-ba1a-1d57-5f9d009a41db">1</a></li>
    <li class=""><a href="/marketing/videoCall/history/businessID/f1f0e0d3-4e47-ba1a-1d57-5f9d009a41db/page/2">2</a></li>
    <li class="next"><a href="/marketing/videoCall/history/businessID/f1f0e0d3-4e47-ba1a-1d57-5f9d009a41db/page/2"><span aria-hidden="true">Next »</span></a></li>
    <li class="hide"><a href="/marketing/videoCall/history/businessID/f1f0e0d3-4e47-ba1a-1d57-5f9d009a41db/page/2"></a></li>
</ul>
```

Now I want to write a click event such as

```
$('#logs_link_pager a').click(function(ev)
```

but I do not want the click event for those `<a>` elements whose parent `<li>` element have either `active` or `disabled` class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `:not` in the selector:

```
$('#logs_link_pager li:not(.active, .disabled) a').click(function(ev) {
    // your code here...
});
```

Alternatively you can check the class of the parent within the click handler itself. This approach would be better if the `active` and `disabled` classes are dynamically changed:

```
$('#logs_link_pager a').click(function(ev) {
    if ($(this).closest('li').is('.active, .disabled')) 
        return;

    // your code here...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `.parents()` to find the parents,

```
$('#logs_link_pager a').click(function(ev) {

   if ($(this).parents('li').hasClass('active')) 

   // Rest of the code...

});
```

Comment: You can only check one class at a time with `hasClass()`

Comment: Sry, its my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

No need of JS for removing `click event` of link.

If you want to remove the click for links whose `li` has class disabled or active then write below css-:

```
#logs_link_pager li.disabled a,
#logs_link_pager li.active a{
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

This will disable links whose parent li has disabled and active classes.
You can also add css to highlight them to show as active or disabled.